# php login and facebook login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, facebook-login

i don't understand how both can work.
I wonna use users table, so is there any tutorial where facebook login and site login can work on same table ?
I need from user to add/modify/delefe staff, but that is connected with users id.

Comment: Your question is extremely messy and unclear. Write it again, in a professionnal, easy to read and clear way and you will get a good answer. I promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just store the user's facebook ID in the users table. This way, when a facebook login occurs, I grab the user's ID and process the login on my site as well.